# Loading DropDownList from model using Helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a bunch of commonly used Lists whcih need to populate dropdownlists. Instead of defining ViewModels with Lists here is what I am doing.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => project.TypeID, new SelectList(@PSS.Helpers.ProjectTypes.ProjectTypesList(),"id","name"))
```

where the Helper class is defined as follows

```
namespace PSS.Helpers
{
    public class ProjectTypes
    {
        public static List<ProjectType> ProjectTypesList()
        {
            MyContext db = new MyContext();
            return db.ProjectTypes.ToList<ProjectType>();

        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with doing this? am I breaking any rules?

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are likely to hit your database more times than you would want to.  Because every time you hit this helper you are creating a new Entity Framework context and hitting the database to get your list of ProjectTypes.  To me, that is bad.

Comment: Agree with Zoran. Use ViewModels for this scenario as the View shouldnt know of your DAL. Its should be independent.

Comment: however if the same dropdownlist is being access in different views tied to different controllers the database is going to be access each time too.

Comment: Well, each scenario is different.  Yes, in an MVC web app where you are making 2 separate requests you would hit the db twice.  But since you wrote the helper to reuse code it could be likely that you would have a scenario where you are using that helper twice within one request or in one view rendering a list of these drop-downs, in which case you would be hitting the database way more times than you would like. Really, it does depend on your scenario, but in the long run, this type of code is likely to cause unwanted bugs/performance issues.